# Python SMTP Change From Name (Spoofing)

Tags: python, smtp

I tried a **working** script that : login and send email **with a spoofing From** and i'm looking to apply this on my own script

The working script is using yagmail library :

```
import yagmail

yag=yagmail.SMTP({"youremail@gmail.com":'SpoofingFrom'}, 'yourpassword')
yag.send("yourdata@gmail.com", "subject", "body")
```

My script is using smtplib library and can't spoof the from :

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
        

smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)

smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login('myemail@gmail.com', 'mypassword')

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = " On this day "
msg['From'] = 'SpoofingFrom'
msg['To'] = data
part2 = MIMEText("body", 'html')
msg.attach(part2)
smtpserver.sendmail('myemail@gmail.com', data, msg.as_string())
```

**How can i make the spoofing name work on my script please**

Comment: Why can't it? Do you get an error?  I'd be surprised if gmail allowed this, to be honest.

Comment: In the first script i don't get error, in the second script i receive from : myemail@gmail.com instead of spoofing

Comment: @ibrahim have you ever figured this one out?